# Use Tor depending on Domain? (via Privoxy)

Tags: browser

I am not sure if this is possible so i am asking here. I want to configure my browser to use privoxy and then make an action. Every time I click or go to a URL that has your standard top-level domain (.com, .net, .org, etc...) nothing will happen but if the domain ends with a .onion, privoxy will use Tor and route my browser through Tor until I leave the .onion domain.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incredibly bad idea from a security perspective. Don't do it!

Allowing a single web browser to browse both `.onion` sites through Tor and regular web sites directly would allow any `.onion` site to determine your public IP address by making a request to a non-`.onion` URL (e.g, using any of the methods suggested at [Get client IP using just JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/391979/149341)). This would defeat the purpose of using Tor for these sites.

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, how would I do it?